# Difference between cv::Mat::t () and cv::transpose()

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, transpose

What is the difference in opencv between these two transposes?

**Using [cv::Mat::t()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aaa428c60ccb6d8ea5de18f63dfac8e11):**

```
cv::Mat a;
a = a.t();
```

**Using [cv::transpose()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga46630ed6c0ea6254a35f447289bd7404):**

```
cv::Mat a;
cv::transpose(a,a);
```

I'm interested in particular about efficiency.

Comment: One appears to be in-place, the other writes to a separate output.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks for your comment. So is it correct to say that the first one is more efficient?

Comment: I don't think that's a sensible question. The two functions do different things. Each of them is as efficient as it can be at what it's doing.

Comment: @KerrekSB From my knowledge, doing something in-place means without allocating memory, which is more a efficient than non-in-place method (like the second one). So, in this particular case, is more efficient the first method. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm with @KerrekSB on this one. If you want to use the transpose for solving another expression then use the first method, if you want the transposed matrix, the second

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no difference. Here's the code for `cv::Mat::t()` from `opencv/modules/core/src/matop.cpp`:

```
MatExpr MatExpr::t() const
{
    MatExpr e;
    op->transpose(*this, e);
    return e;
}
```

So `cv::Mat::t()` just calls `cv::transpose()`.