# C++ OpenCV transpose/permute image axes

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, transpose

I'm having a hard time to code this python line in C++:

Python:

```
frame_nn = cv2.cvtColor(padded, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).transpose(2,0,1).astype(np.float32)[None,]
```

What I already got:

```
cv::cvtColor(image_pd, image_pd, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
image_pd.convertTo(image_f, CV_32F);
```

How do I transpose a 3D maxtrix / image in C++? Basically what is the equivalent of `image = numpy.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))` in C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between cv::Mat::t () and cv::transpose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310433/difference-between-cvmatt-and-cvtranspose)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve in that line in Python? What is the context? Most of the conversions you have there are simply to change from the OpenCV shape/ordering to NumPy. You're not using NumPy in C++, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to change the image to a format NumPy likes.

Comment: transpose((2,0,1)) converts from HWC to CHW channel order...

Comment: Note that `cv::transpose()` will *only* transpose the first two dimensions, so it is not applicable if you really want to permute all 3 axes.

Answer (score 12):

to convert from HWC to CHW channel order, you can use this (stolen from `blobFromImage())`:

```
int siz[] = {3, img.rows, img.cols};
Mat chw(3, siz, CV_8U);
vector<Mat> planes = {
    Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U, img.ptr(0)), // swap 0 and 2 and you can avoid the bgr->rgb conversion !
    Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U, img.ptr(1)),
    Mat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8U, img.ptr(2))
};
split(img, planes);
chw.convertTo(chw, CV_32F);
```

[edit]
from 4.6.0 on, you can also use [transposeND()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab1b1274b4a563be34cdfa55b8919a4ec)

```
Mat src=...
Mat dst;
transposeND(src, {2,0,1}, dst);
```

Comment: The `img.ptr(N)` parts in your code should be `chw.ptr(N)`.